# Random Number Generator and Variance

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, random

Hi Math Stack Exchange Community,

I've been trying to solve this question related to variance and discrete random variables and I couldn't find a way to approach and solve this question. I would be glad if you could help. Thanks in advance.

```
A random number generator​ (RNG) is designed to generate random numbers from 1 to 8. Let X and Y be the
two numbers that appear when the RNG is run twice.

(a) What is the variance of the random variable 2X - Y?
(b) What is the variance of the random variable X+4Y-3?
```

Comment: Note that the phrase "random numbers from 1 to 8" is vague: Random numbers _from what distribution_?  Random _integers_ or random _real numbers_?  Are the numbers independent and identically distributed?  Is the interval closed, open, half-open, half-closed?

Comment: Unfortunately, the question does not tell these details. @PeterO.